@PreDestroy not getting invoked while application shutdown
I have a spring webflux application running on ECS. Intent is whenever the instances scale-in or are terminated (during deployment or otherwise), the @PreDestroy method within the Processor.java should be executed.
On local, while running the application on IntelliJ, when the application is stopped, the @PreDestroy annotated method is getting invoked. But it is not working when deployed on ECS.
I found various links stating that while running the application though shell script the shell absorbs the signals and does not pass it through to the application. For that, I used exec command in entrypoint.sh, but this is still not working.
Dockerfile
ARG OPENJDK_DIGEST
FROM openjdk:8-jre@${OPENJDK_DIGEST}

LABEL org.opencontainers.image.authors="xxxx.xxx.com"

VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
ARG PROFILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENV PROFILE_ENV=${PROFILE}
EXPOSE 8080
COPY entrypoint.sh /
COPY job.sh /
COPY tini-arm64 /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

entrypoint.sh
# Execute the Java application
exec java -Dspring.profiles.active=${PROFILE_ENV} \
          -XX:+UseG1GC \
          -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom \
          -Dloader.main=com.paytmlabs.adtech.adtechdecisionengine.AdTechDecisionEngineApplication.java \
          -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=2g \
          -jar app.jar

Processor.java
@Slf4j
@Component
@DependsOn({"dep1", "dep2", "dep3", "dep4"})
public class AuditSinkEventProcessor extends SinkEventProcessor {

  .
  .
  .

  @PreDestroy
  public void destroy() {
    this.stopSink();
    this.processParquetFiles(true);
  }
}

References

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/graceful-shutdowns-with-ecs/
https://veithen.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html
https://vsupalov.com/docker-compose-stop-slow/

Any suggestions?

has probably have something to do with the way you shutdown ur application - if it is forced shutdown (e.g. kill process) then predestroy won't have a chance to be executed. This article seems to be covering ur issue https://medium.com/viascom/graceful-shutdowns-for-containerized-spring-boot-applications-d9c465ce4fd9

As per ECS definition, it first sends the SIGTERM and then after a specified timeout (stopTimeout), it sends the SIGKILL. The stopTimeout has been configured as 1200 seconds. Also, the changes suggested in the application properties are also applied. The challenge is getting the SIGTERM event to the application so that it can execute the @PreDestroy annotated methods.

Are you sure you have the Spring's Shutdown Hook registered? With an automatic configured spring it's the default state, but if you setup it manually you have to do springContext.registerShutdownHook() or similar, depending on how you run it.
